# converting postgresql interval format to something usable in php

Tags: php, postgresql

I have a function in PHP which returns the time elapsed from a postgresql database in the following format

```
00:34:01.024416
```

in php this data gets stored as "String" which is not much use. What can I use in PHP so I can do calculations on the data provided by the database?

Comment: How about converting it into total micro seconds elapsed?

Comment: @NandakumarV can you show me an example of how that is done with PHP? I come from a Java background with no experience in PHP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert the data from the postgres to milliseconds or microseconds. This can be stored in the PHP and later be used to manipulate the total time taken... A query like the one below will help you in this

```
SELECT
(EXTRACT (HOURS FROM TIME '00:34:01.024416') * 3600000) :: int AS "hour-millisecond",
(EXTRACT (MINUTE FROM TIME '00:34:01.024416') * 60000) :: int AS "minute-millisecond",
(EXTRACT (SECOND FROM TIME '00:34:01.024416') * 1000) :: int AS "second-millisecond",
(EXTRACT (MILLISECONDS FROM TIME '00:34:01.024416')) :: int AS "millisecond"
```

---

```
SELECT (EXTRACT (HOURS FROM TIME '00:34:01.024416') * 3600000) :: int + 
(EXTRACT (MINUTE FROM TIME '00:34:01.024416') * 60000) :: int + 
(EXTRACT (SECOND FROM TIME '00:34:01.024416') * 1000) :: int + 
(EXTRACT (MILLISECONDS FROM TIME '00:34:01.024416')) :: int AS millisecondelapsed
```

---

**[EDIT]**

```
SELECT (EXTRACT (HOURS FROM  elapsedtime_result.elapsedtime) * 3600000) :: int + 
(EXTRACT (MINUTE FROM  elapsedtime_result.elapsedtime) * 60000) :: int + 
(EXTRACT (SECOND FROM  elapsedtime_result.elapsedtime) * 1000) :: int + 
(EXTRACT (MILLISECONDS FROM  elapsedtime_result.elapsedtime)) :: int AS millisecondelapsed 
FROM (SELECT current_timestamp - max(createdon) elapsedtime FROM testtable) AS elapsedtime_result
```

Comment: Is there anyway to use a select statement inside that query instead of giving the time statically? So instead of '00:34:01.024416' having a query in there which would return interval.